# How I can write file readable for other applications?

Tags: android, file, sd-card

My application creates a text file. I want that users to have easy access to these files.  I write this text file  them on the sdcard.   I want to allow users to edit the file with other programs.
I see these files using the File Explorer, but I can not see using file manager.

```
String extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        try{
    String pathPrefix = extPath + "/Android/data/" +      getApplication().getPackageName() + "/cache/";
    //File extPathFile = getExternalFilesDir(pathPrefix+FileName);
    Log.d("TAG", "pathPrefix="+pathPrefix);
    Log.d("TAG", "FileName="+FileName);
    File file = new File(pathPrefix, FileName+".txt");
    if(file.exists()){
    Log.d("TAG", "File("+pathPrefix+FileName+")exist"); 
    };
   OutputStreamWriter outStream = 
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Logcat:

```
01-22 14:26:15.834: D/TAG(14290): pathPrefix=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mast.avalons/cache/
01-22 14:26:15.834: D/TAG(14290): FileName=S000004_21-10-2011
01-22 14:26:16.044: D/TAG(14290): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mast.avalons/cache/S000004_21-10-2011.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create intermediate directories :

```
new File(pathPrefix).mkdirs();
```